# Select the dept names where the sum of their employees' salaries is greater than the average of all departments'

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have table emp containing columns empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno and table dept containing columns deptno, dname, loc

We're selecting the dname where the sum of employee salaries is greater than the average sums of salaries from all departments

I'm unfamiliar with using multiple SELECTs in a single query, this is what I try:

```
SELECT d.dname FROM emp e
JOIN dept d ON e.deptno = d.deptno
GROUP BY d.deptno HAVING SUM(e.sal) >
                        (SELECT AVG(sal) FROM emp
                        GROUP BY deptno)
```

Gives an error for having multiples lines returned by the second select, when I experimented I did not find a way to match the right single lines

How do you select the right dnames?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `avg()over()` window function to get the average of department wise salary sum. Then use this in cte and just select the departments with sum of salary greater than the average of sums.

Schema and inert statements:

```
 create table emp(empno varchar(100), ename varchar(100), job varchar(100), mgr varchar(100), hiredate date, sal int, comm int, deptno varchar(100));
 insert into emp values('e01','Adam',null,null,'01-01-2021',10000,null,'D01');
 insert into emp values('e02','Zaid',null,null,'01-01-2021',12000,null,'D01');
 insert into emp values('e03','Noor',null,null,'01-01-2021',20000,null,'D02');
 insert into emp values('e04','Seth',null,null,'01-01-2021',12000,null,'D03');

 create table dept (deptno varchar(100),dname varchar(100));
 insert into dept values('D01','HR');
 insert into dept values('D02','IT');
 insert into dept values('D03','Sales');
```

Query:

```
 with cte as
 ( 
   SELECT deptno, SUM(sal) AS salary_sum  ,avg(sum(sal))over() salary_average
   FROM   emp
   GROUP BY deptno
 )
 select *
 from cte c inner join dept d 
 on c.deptno=d.deptno
 where salary_sum>salary_average
```

Output:

| deptno | salary_sum | salary_average | deptno | dname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D01 | 22000 | 18000.000000000000 | D01 | HR |
| D02 | 20000 | 18000.000000000000 | D02 | IT |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4ff7cccfa1c65a674c22e2b84edb4d07)*

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery returns the average salary per department instead of the average of the sum of salaries:

```sql
SELECT d.dname FROM emp e
JOIN dept d ON e.deptno = d.deptno
GROUP BY d.deptno HAVING SUM(e.sal) >
                        (SELECT AVG(s) 
                         FROM   (SELECT SUM(sal) AS s  
                                 FROM   emp
                                 GROUP BY deptno) t
                        )
```